# Write a user input method in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, java.util.scanner

I'm writing JDBC in Java, my thought is to write a method called userInsertCruise, which can make user input the data, and these data will add a new row into my database table.

Here is my code look like:

```
public class Insert_Cruise {
   public void userInsertCruise(Date sailingDate, Date returnDate,String departurePort,
        String shipName, String portOfCalls, String cruiseSerialNumber, int passengerID){

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Input the sailing date:");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        sailingDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(sc1.next());

        System.out.println("Input the return date :");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        returnDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(sc2.next());

        System.out.println("Input the departure port:");
        Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        departurePort = sc3.next();

        System.out.println("Input the ship name");
        Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        shipName = sc4.next();

        System.out.println("Input the ports of calls:");
        Scanner sc5 = new Scanner(System.in);
        portOfCalls = sc5.next();

        System.out.println("Input the cruise serial number:");
        Scanner sc6 = new Scanner(System.in);
        cruiseSerialNumber = sc5.next();

        System.out.println("Input the passenger ID:");
        Scanner sc7 = new Scanner(System.in);
        passengerID = sc7.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Are you finish establish your data? Y/N");
        Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = ans.next();

        if(answer != "y"){
            break;
        }else{
            continue;
        }

    public  void insertCruise() throws SQLException
{

    String url = ("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mydata");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

   try {
    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CRUISE ("
        + "SAILING_DATE, RETURN_DATE, DEPARTURE_PORT, SHIP_NAME, 
      PORTS_OF_CALLS, CRUISE_SERIAL_NUMBER, PASSENGER_ID_NUMBER) "
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

} catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("Record Already exists.");
}

}
```

Then I want to call the method in main:

```
Insert_Cruise insert = new Insert_Cruise();
insert.userInsertCruise(sailingDate, returnDate, passward, username, passward, username, 0);
insert.insertCruise();
```

However, it does not work. Because I have no parameter to input in the userInsertCruise method.

The reason that I don't want to use Scanner in the main method is it would make the main method too long. And I have to make user can insert row in different tables in my database, if I write all the scanner in main, it would be very mess.
Is there any method to fix this problem?

Comment: You're missing the point of method arguments. A method defines arguments when it needs to get its input from the caller. For examplt, the println() method doesn't know what to print on its own, so you pass it the string to print. Your method figures out what to insert on its own, by asking the user and reading what he/she types in. So it shouldn't have arguments.

Comment: You're also trying to declare a method inside another method. That's not valid.

Comment: But if the method userInsertCruise do not have parameters, then when I conduct this method in main, the user can not input anything. Can you clarify more ??

Comment: Here's how that should look like: main calls method getDataAndInsert() without arguments. This method gets all the data from the user. Once it has all the data to insert, then it calls another method insert(), that takes all the gathered data as arguments, and inserts them to the database.

Comment: Another even better option would be to declare a User class, that could be returned by a method. The main would then look like `User user = getUserData(); insertUser(user);`.

Comment: It looks like all your parameters should actually just be declared as local variables inside the userInsertCruise method.  Also, you don't need to create a new Scanner each time you want to get user input. You can just keep calling sc1.next() if you wanted.